# How do you ignore LessJS CSS errors in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error, less

I have my problems tab in eclipse blowing up with over 200 + errors on valid CSS.

Example Code:

```
& > a {font-size: 12px;padding:0 0 0 10px;color:#86bffb;}

.default {filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#58a3dd', endColorstr='#2c6dcc',GradientType=0 );}
```

Is there anyway to ignore these errors?

Comment: Eclipse from eclipse.org doesn't come with a CSS Validator. What sort of errors are you seeing, and what plug-in is reporting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nether standard Eclipse nor Eclipse Java EE IDE have validators for CSS files. So it is probably 3rd party eclipse extension which does validation. This extension could extend WST Validation framework or provide its own validation implementation.

In first case validation settings related to what kind files should be included/excluded from validation process located in Window->Preferences... dialog inside Validation category. The severity level settings for detected problems are usually located in category under editor preferences. For example for HTML files problem severity level preferences are located in Web->HTML Files->Editor->Validation category of Window->Preferences... dialog.

In second case it could be anywhere in global preferences for workspace or local preferences for project.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer above, one common cause of this seems to be the e(fx)clipse plugin for JavaFX. To turn off validation in this case, deselect the 'compiler is activated' option.

[image: E(fx)clipse settings]